# How does combining special relativity with quantum mechanics produce spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-spin

I have read and heard that the intrinsic property of spin that elementary particles have comes from combining special relativity with quantum mechanics.  How does combining special relativity with quantum mechanics produce spin and how does it relate to the fact that spin can either be integer or half integer and the Pauli Exclusion Principle?

Comment: Please see the top voted answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67616/ If you have any questions that doesn't answer, I can try my hand at it.