# Connection between spin and lorentz invariance

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry

I came across this statement in the book "Quantum Field theory and the Standard Model" by Matthew Schwartz.

> "There is a deep connection between Spin and Lorentz invariance that is obscure in Non Relativistic Quantum Mechanics"

What is the connection between Spin and Lorentz Invariance? Is Spin a relativistic effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spin - where does it come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67616/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirac predicted theoretically the electron spin by application of  Special Relativity Principles to Quantum Mechanics. The derivation of his famous equation is based on the demand of Lorentz covariance.